# How to verify not authorized users in ASP.NET MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Unfortunately I didn't find answer that approached me, so I hope that somebody could give me an advice.

I can take users ip, but it can be dynamic, so this is not a 100% guarantee and also on one ip there can be several users.

Also I can use [anonymousIdentification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-4.0/91ka2e6a(v=vs.100)).

```
<anonymousIdentification
        enabled="true"
        cookieless="UseCookies"
        cookieName=".ASPXANONYMOUS"
        cookieTimeout="30"
        cookiePath="/"
        cookieRequireSSL="false"
        cookieSlidingExpiration = "true"
        cookieProtection="Validation"
      />
```

But it based on coockies that easily could be turned off or cleared.

As i know somebody use [evercoockie](https://github.com/samyk/evercookie), but I thing it's too rough, maybe I'm wrong.

So I would like to know if it is possible to identify users more reliably both for computers and for mobile devices.

Answer (score 0):

You can generate a GUID for each guest and save it in a cookie. So each time a user comes it will check for the cookie. You can then use the GUID as an identifier for other entities instead of a User ID. I have used this system for a page that allows both guests and users to use the services. It has to be GUID, not an int, so the cookie can not be manipulated manually.

```
    public Guid InitGuestCookie()
    {
        if (Request.Cookies.AllKeys.Contains(Utils.Constants.GuestId))
        {
            var id = Request.Cookies[Utils.Constants.GuestId];

            if (id != null)
            {
                var guid = new Guid(id.Value);
                // Make sure this guid exists as a registered guest
                var guest = _guestService.GetById(guid);
                if (guest != null)
                {
                    return guest.Id;
                }
            }
        }

        var newGuest = CreateGuest();
        var cookie = new HttpCookie(Utils.Constants.GuestId, newGuest.Id.ToString());
        Response.Cookies.Set(cookie);
        return newGuest.Id;
    }

    public Guid GuestId { get; set; }

    public Guest CreateGuest()
    {
        var guid = Guid.NewGuid();
        var newGuest = new Guest()
        {
            CreateDate = DateTime.Now,
            LastUsageDate = DateTime.Now,
            Id = guid,
        };

        _guestService.AddOrUpdate(newGuest);
        return newGuest;
    }
```

And in the Init method of the controller I call:

```
    protected override void Initialize(RequestContext requestContext)
    {
        base.Initialize(requestContext);
        GuestId = InitGuestCookie();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I still not understand: if user visit my site I generate guid for that user and put it in coockie. Then for some reason he cleared browser's coockies. And if that user visit site again I can identify him by old guid or I generate new?

Comment: If he loses the cookie he loses the data, but Evercookie should help you here. I think it's the best way to ID a person without logging in. Feel free to comment if you find a better solution.